# How to compare entire multidimensional arrays? - WinForms VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, multidimensional-array

How can I compare two entire multidimensional arrays in WinForms VB.NET?

My code is checking to see whether some `Sub`s will change the content of an array.

In order to do this, it makes a carbon copy of the original array *before* the subs have been executed. This carbon copy is left untouched until after the sub has happened. Once it's done the `Sub`, I want to see whether anything in the main array has changed. Here's my current code:

```
If possible = "not possible" Then 'If grid is full
        'Check whether something can be done at all
        For x = 0 To 5
            For y = 0 To 5
                copyarray(x, y) = bigarray(x, y)
            Next
        Next

        Dim movementarray() As String = {"up", "down", "left", "right"}
        For i = 0 To 3
            direction = movementarray(i)
            moveblocks()
        Next
        If copyarray = bigarray Then
            'This throws an error
        End If
End If
```

N.B. `copyarray` is the carbon copy of `bigarray`; `moveblocks()` is the `Sub` which I want to see whether it changes anything; and `possible` is simply a prerequisite to this code being run.

How do I do this? I ask because Visual Basic throws the following error in respect to the last `If` statement:

> Error 1:  Operator '=' is not defined for types '2-dimensional array of Integer' and '2-dimensional array of Integer'. Use 'Is' operator to compare two reference types.  My Game\Form1.vb    Line 282    Character 16    My Program

Comment: It might be easier to make `MoveBlocks` a function which returns True/False if it changes anything.  Otherwise, you will need to iterate and compare elements one way or another to detect a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. Here's my solution:

```
Private Function whatever() as Boolean
    If possible = "not possible" Then 'If grid is full
        'Check whether something can be done at all
        For x = 0 To 5
            For y = 0 To 5
                copyarray(x, y) = bigarray(x, y)
            Next
        Next

        Dim movementarray() As String = {"up", "down", "left", "right"}
        For i = 0 To 3
            direction = movementarray(i)
            moveblocks()
        Next

        Dim changed as Boolean = False
        For i = 0 to 5
            For j = 0 to 5
                If Not copyarray(i, j) = bigarray(i, j) Then Return True : Exit Function
            Next
        Next

    Return False
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```